# Event listeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Does JavaScript have a sort of event listeners?

My scenario:
I want to execute `Inc` function twice with different parameters, first execution of `Inc` and then  the second execution, but the second execution must be executed after X seconds (`settimeout`...) after the first `Inc` function is **completed** (all it's iterations, as soon as `clearInterval` ).

So I need sort of event and a listener (of-course it must be asynchronous).
What can you suggest? (please no jQuery...)

```
function Inc(val1,val2){                               
     var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
          if (val1 > val2) clearInterval(intervalID);
          val1= val1 + 10;                        
      }, 400);
                
}
```

Comment: No. you can attach to some built-in event handlers for events in Window, Document and some DOM elements (onclick, onload, onunload, etc.) but you have to mimic "real" event handler functionality through other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Well, since I don't know why you don't want it to know about the continuation, here's another suggestion with the exact same semantics but maybe a desirable syntax, now there is a simulation of event delegation anyway :) (thing is, you need the Inc function to somehow report completion):

```
function Inc(val1,val2){
    var handle = { oncomplete: null };

    var intervalID = setInterval(function(){

        if (val1 > val2)
        { 
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            if (handle.oncomplete) handle.oncomplete();
        }

        val1 = val1 + 10;

    }, 400);

    return handle;
}

Inc(10, 40).oncomplete = function(){ alert("Finish"); };
```

**Previous:** Something like this should to the trick (I did not test it though):

```
function Inc(val1,val2, continuation){                               
 var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
  if (val1 > val2)
  { 
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    if (continuation) continuation();
  }

  val1 = val1 + 10;                        
 }, 400); }
```

Then call it like this:

```
Inc(x, y, function(){ Inc(y, z); });
```

Comment: but in this case Inc "knows" about the second Inc (though it anonymous but still knows) i don't want that.

Comment: I added a new suggestion but now, you have to return a handle so not a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

I usually try to stay away from *timeouts*, especially if they deal with something that requires recursion.

But why do you need recursion if the function is only executed twice?

```
// call Inc the first time
Inc();

// this will execute only after the first Inc(); is done.
// call Inc the second time after X seconds
setTimeout(Inc, 400);
```

Comment: Inc foo is for animation (it has more code of course), so I need setinterval

Comment: I run Inc first time to animate element in one direction and then, after x seconds I use same inc to animate object in another direction

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no type of standarized custom-eventing, but you are making the work-around.

Calling a "delegate" this way:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // CALL Inc with different params, this is your "event"
};

function Inc(val1, val2) {
   setInterval(myFunction,400);
}
```

Short answer, not for custom events (only DOM-standard events), but you can fake it.